# Javascript regex- remove all spaces in string except between words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a bit of a conundrum.

I have a jquery modal dialog form that is bound to a click event of a table within an accordion.  On click of a row, the dialog opens up with the input fields and other elements populated with the table row data.

As part of the form, I'd like to include the accordion header text.  I can extract out the text via

```
var activeClient = $("#strat_key_management").accordion("option", "active");
var client = $("#strat_key_management h2").eq(activeClient).text();
```

but there are many newlines and spaces within the text, as shown:

```
"\n                         CLIENT NAME FOO BAR BUZZ   \n                           \n                              \n                          \n                      "
```

I can remove the newlines via

```
client = client.replace(/\n\gm, "");
```

and this produces

```
"                           CLIENT NAME FOO BAR BUZZ   "
```

where the quotes show the beginning and end of the string.

How can I remove the spaces surrounding `CLIENT NAME FOO BAR BUZZ` but not within?

Comment: Doesn't `$.trim` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"")` to trim spaces from the start and end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a built-in `$.trim`. In modern browsers there's `String.prototype.trim`:

```
$.trim(text); // jQuery

// OR

text.trim(); // modern browsers
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.trim()`:

```
var trimmed = client.trim();
```