# Jquery remove all spaces in string except between words not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to remove all white spaces from string except except between words,i try the following,but its not working.

**Input String**

```
=  IF  ( @F_28º@FC_89º =  " @Very strongº "  , 100 ,  IF  ( @F_28º@FC_89º =  " @Above Averageº "  , 75 ,  IF  ( @F_28º@FC_89º =  " @Averageº "  , 50 ,  IF  ( @F_28º@FC_89º =  " @Below Averageº "  , 25 ,  IF  ( @F_28º@FC_89º =  " @Cannot determineº "  , 0 ,  IF  ( @F_28º@FC_89º =  " @Poorº "  , 0 , 0 )  )  )  )  )  )
```

I want to remove all spaces except words like

- Very strong
- Above Average
  etc

I tried this regex from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17767576/1267304):

```
str.replace(/\s/g, '')
```

but its also not working.

Comment: Show the desired output, your question is unclear.

Comment: it seems like you want to remove all spaces except spaces that appear between `@` and `º` - would that be a fair assessment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this `\s+(?![a-zA-Z])`?

Applied to the string you posted, the result is:

```
= IF(@F_28º@FC_89º="@Very strongº",100, IF(@F_28º@FC_89º="@Above Averageº",75, IF(@F_28º@FC_89º="@Averageº",50, IF(@F_28º@FC_89º="@Below Averageº",25, IF(@F_28º@FC_89º="@Cannot determineº",0, IF(@F_28º@FC_89º="@Poorº",0,0))))))
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bwzk6tL/)**</kbd>

This one `\s+(?![a-zA-Z])|\s+(?=IF)` also removes spaces before `IF` word:

```
=IF(@F_28º@FC_89º="@Very strongº",100,IF(@F_28º@FC_89º="@Above Averageº",75,IF(@F_28º@FC_89º="@Averageº",50,IF(@F_28º@FC_89º="@Below Averageº",25,IF(@F_28º@FC_89º="@Cannot determineº",0,IF(@F_28º@FC_89º="@Poorº",0,0))))))
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bwzk6tL/1/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If I am understand correctly you want to trim the leading and trailing spaces in the string?

```
$.trim(str);
```

Comment: If you're not sure of what the OP wants please don't post an answer. When you have more reputation you'll be able to comment and ask for details like this before posting your answer.